# Communicating with a running process

Tags: python, ipc

We have:

- A Python based server (A)
- A running command-line application (on the same Linux machine) which is able to read `stdin`, computes something and provides the output into `stdout` (B)

What is the best (most elegant) way how to send an input from (A) to `stdin` of (B), and wait for an answer from (B), i.e read its `stdout`?

Comment: Whatever you do here, be careful to avoid a deadlock in which A and B are both waiting on each other to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Deestan pointed subprocess,module, is an elegant and proven one. We use subprocess a lot when we have to run commands from python.

Ours mostly involves running a command, mostly in-house built, and capturing its output. Our wrapper to run such commands looks thus.

```
import subprocess
def _run_command( _args, input=[],withShell=False):
    """
    Pass args as array, like ['echo', 'hello']
    Waits for completion and returns
    tuple (returncode, stdout, stderr)
    """
    p = subprocess.Popen(_args, shell = withShell,
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    [p.stdin.write(v) for v in input]
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    return p.returncode, stdout, stderr

_,op,er = _run_command(['cat'],["this","is","for","testing"])
value="".join(op)
print value

_,op,er = _run_command(['ls',"/tmp"])
value="".join(op)
print value
```

If your input to **B** is minimal then subprocess is a **yes**.

Comment: Please, as I have mentioned above, what about if the sub-process runs for a very long time (not once)?

Comment: Elaborate in your question how process B is started and terminated. Give sample input/output. PS: If process A & B are started async, then you should opt for socket.

Answer (score 2):

If you spawn (B) using Python's `subprocess` module from the standard library, you can set up (B)'s `stdin` and `stdout` as byte buffers readable and writable by (A).

```
b = Popen(["b.exe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
b.stdin.write("OHAI\n")
print(b.stdout.readline())
```

For your given example, it's easiest to use `communicate`, as that takes care to avoid deadlocks for you:

```
b = Popen(["b.exe"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
b_out = b.communicate("OHAI\n")[0]
print(b_out)
```

http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/subprocess.html

http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

If there's a lot of 2-way communication, you should take care to avoid deadlocks because of full buffers.  If your communication pattern gives this type of problem, you should consider using `socket` communication instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Popen.communicate()` is not the option, because the sub-process (B) runs "forever".

Comment: Then communicate via stdin.write and stdout.read as in the first example.