# How to communicate to an active process/subprocess?

Tags: java, python, subprocess

I'm creating a Python Script that would intersect itself into an active process terminal. So, if I want to send commands like "say Hello World!" or "ban username bad User" and etc.

I tried using the subprocess library, though I'm very unfamiliar with it at the moment; originally I was using sockets and connecting to the service via Rcon protocols. Though, I found this to be a major security risk, if the Rcon protocol was exposed to the Internet.

My current environment to test is with a Minecraft Server.

I know that the error that is produced from the Java Application isn't caused locally, I believe this has to deal with that I'm using subprocessing on it or not executing my subprocess correctly.

Other Research:
[Communicating with a running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188389/communicating-with-a-running-process)
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen
https://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

```
import subprocess
import threading

ENV = {}

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ['java', '-jar', 'server.jar'], 
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    env=ENV,
    encoding='utf8'
)


def console():
    while(True):
        cmd = input('> ')
        if cmd.strip() != '':
            out = proc.communicate(cmd)[0]
            print(out)
            #proc.stdin.write(cmd)
            #print(proc.stdout.readline())
        #proc.stdin.write('say Hello World!')
        #print(proc.stdout.readline())

t1 = threading.Thread(target=console)
t1.start()
```

Expected:
I would like to see that my command went through the process's terminal.

Current Output:

```
python rcon.py
> say hello
[09:17:43] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, destination] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [Player, 0123, @e, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[09:17:43] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[09:17:43] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, location] and [teleport, targets] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[09:17:43] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets] and [teleport, destination] with inputs: [Player, 0123, dd12be42-52a9-4a91-a8a1-11c01849e498]
[09:17:43] [main/WARN]: Ambiguity between arguments [teleport, targets, location] and [teleport, targets, destination] with inputs: [0.1 -0.5 .9, 0 0 0]
[09:17:43] [main/INFO]: Loaded 0 recipes
[09:17:43] [main/INFO]: Loaded 0 advancements
[09:17:44] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.13.2
[09:17:44] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[09:17:44] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[09:17:44] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[09:17:44] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[09:17:44] [Server thread/INFO]: Using default channel type
[09:17:44] [Server thread/ERROR]: Encountered an unexpected exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:88) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:59) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:77) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:72) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:59) ~[server.jar:?]
        at ub.f(SourceFile:55) ~[server.jar:?]
        at xn.a(SourceFile:16) ~[server.jar:?]
        at ub.a(SourceFile:111) ~[server.jar:?]
        at so.d(SourceFile:181) ~[server.jar:?]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:566) [server.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:?]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:177) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:151) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:127) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:36) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84) ~[server.jar:?]
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:175) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:151) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:127) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:36) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84) ~[server.jar:?]
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: socket
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.serverSocket(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openServerSocketChannel(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.openSelector(NioEventLoop.java:175) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.<init>(NioEventLoop.java:151) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:127) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.newChild(NioEventLoopGroup.java:36) ~[server.jar:?]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:84) ~[server.jar:?]
        ... 12 more
[09:17:54] [Server thread/ERROR]: This crash report has been saved to: D:\WorkSpace\Python\Apps\MC\crash-reports\crash-2019-01-09_09.17.54-server.txt
[09:17:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[09:17:54] [Server thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
[09:17:54] [Server Shutdown Thread/INFO]: Stopping server
[09:17:54] [Server Shutdown Thread/INFO]: Saving worlds
```

Thank you, and I would greatly appreciate any advise or pointers on this issue.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643301/unrecognized-windows-sockets-error-10106-create-when-starting-tomcat-in-the-co) for winsock error 10106.

Comment: @rustyx I appreciate your response, though if you referencing that this is a Malware situation. I can guarantee that it is not, I tested my application on multiple different Operating Systems and separate machines. To verify that this isn't local machine issue. As I said before in my introduction post, I think it has to deal with using subprocessing in python.

But for being a winsock, I believe that the only problem is having a subprocess running over the application could potentially block sockets.